# kong : replicate data across multiple servers

Tags: postgresql, docker, kong

I am using a kong api gateway. How to use the same data across multiple kong server instances?

I am deploying kong on docker containers. I tried committing all the postgresql data and generating a new docker postgre db image from it. I thought reusing this image would solve this problem, but that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a database to store the configuration, all your kong nodes will get data from this single source.

You can use [deck](https://github.com/Kong/deck) to automatize your deployment